# Adding a join to this LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, select, join

so I am nearly complete with figuring out how to do this entire LINQ query (I am just now learning) I need to join another table called Project to this linq query and include a field called ProposedCompletionDate.

Right now it will Filter out entries between a min and max date I called FilterProjectAfterDate and FilterProjectBeforeDate and counts the TimeWorked for each unique Project Name in TimeEntries.

My Project table contains some additional information I would like to include in this query, how would I go about joining the Project table to this current query? The keys for the Project table are ProjectName and Phase.

Here are the data types for my DB tables
[Project Table Data Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWcMv.png),
[TimeEntry Table Data Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Ba7.png)

My current query returns this information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtLHC.png)

```
var result = context.TimeEntries.Where(Entry => Entry.Date >= FilterProjectAfterDate 
                                            && Entry.Date <= FilterProjectBeforerDate 
                                            && (FilterProjectName != null ? Entry.ProjectName.Contains(FilterProjectName) : true))
                    .GroupBy(m => new { m.ProjectName, m.Phase })
                    .Select(m => new {
                        Name = m.Key.ProjectName,
                        Phase = m.Key.Phase,
                        TimeWorked = m.Sum(o => o.TimeWorked)

          });
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you tried using the `Join` extension method?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do but I have no idea where I should be putting it in my statement? Or exactly how to use it. Sorry for my ignorance this is literally my first day going over this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = ctx.TimeEntries
    .Where(q => q.Date >= FilterProjectAfterDate)
    .Where(q => q.Date <= FilterProjectBeforerDate)
    .WhereIf(FilterProjectName != null, q => q.ProjectName.Contains(FilterProjectName))
    .GroupBy(q => new { q.ProjectName, q.Phase })
    .Join(ctx.Projects, 
          q => new { q.Key.ProjectName, q.Key.Phase },
          w => new { w.ProjectName, w.Phase },
          (q, w) => new { te = q, proj = w })
    .Select(q => new
    {
        Name = q.te.Key.ProjectName,
        Phase = q.te.Key.Phase,
        TimeWorked = q.te.Sum(w => w.TimeWorked),
        ProposedCompletionDate = q.proj.ProposedCompletionDate
    });
```

WhereIf extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(
   this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, 
   Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (condition)
        return source.Where(predicate);
    else
        return source;
}
```

Comment: While this answers the question, it could be improved by briefly summarizing what you've done and why.

Comment: Also, I think `Phase` should be part of the `Join`.

Comment: @EricObermuller The updated code includes `Phase` now? What do you mean how it is working?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the update before I posted that. It is working perfectly, could you go into depth how that .Join extension method is working? Not sure why you are using q => new {...} when q is used above that? Also what is the new {te = q, proj = w} for right before the select?

Comment: Perhaps the documentation on [`Enumerable.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___2__) would help? (I don't think `IQueryable.Join` isn't explained as clearly.)